# Regex re.findall can only extract half of data

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall

I use regext to find all the email address from a str, and however, sometimes email address are cut and only part of one address is returned.

```
import re

regex=r'(\w{1,}((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}@\w{1,}((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}\.\w{1,})'

str2fetch='''


wwwr@h.com.h.ki.l =》1  #==》wwwr@h.com.h.ki

sdfsd

2@mail2.4.sdu.edu.cn.u.163.com #=>2@mail2.4.sdu.edu.cn

0@0.0
1@1.1.1
1@123434.22222.333.4444.com
AAAAAA2@p.2-t.2.3o.2.abcd4 #=>aaaaaa2@p.2-t.2.3o

AAAAAA2@p.2t.2.3o.2.abcd4   #=>aaaaaa2@p.2t

AAAAAA2@p.2-t.2p.3o.2.abcd4  #=>aaaaaa2@p.2-t.2p

DAAAAAA2@p.2p-t.2.3o.2.abcd4  #=>daaaaaa2@p.2p

3@3.3.3.3.3
4@4.4.4.4.4.4
'''
emailList=list(set(re.findall(regex,str2fetch.lower())))

print(emailList)
```

The left part is the supposed result, however, the right result is given.

```
wwwr@h.com.h.ki.l =》1  #==》wwwr@h.com.h.ki

AAAAAA2@p.2-t.2.3o.2.abcd4 #=>aaaaaa2@p.2-t.2.3o

AAAAAA2@p.2t.2.3o.2.abcd4   #=>aaaaaa2@p.2t

AAAAAA2@p.2-t.2p.3o.2.abcd4  #=>aaaaaa2@p.2-t.2p

DAAAAAA2@p.2p-t.2.3o.2.abcd4  #=>daaaaaa2@p.2p
```

Comment: regex = r'(\w{1,}((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}@\w{1,}((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}\.\w{1,})'
        a='\w{1,}'  #any digital or alphabet with length >1
        b='((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}'    #started by dot|_|-|any digital/alphabet str, +any digital/alphabet str
        c='@'
        d='\w{1,}'  #any digital or alphabet with length >1
        e='((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}'  #started by dot|_|-|any digital/alphabet str, +any digital/alphabet str
        f='\.\w{1,}' #dot+any digital or alphabet with length >1

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = r'(\w{1,}((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}@\w{1,}((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}\.\w{1,})'
    a='\w{1,}'  #any digital or alphabet with length >1
    b='((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}'    #started by dot|_|-|any digital/alphabet str, +any digital/alphabet str
    c='@'
    d='\w{1,}'  #any digital or alphabet with length >1
    e='((\.|_|-|\w)[\w]){0,}'  #started by dot|_|-|any digital/alphabet str, +any digital/alphabet str
    f='\.\w{1,}' #dot+any digital or alphabet with length >1
```